# Why HTTP PATCH request method is not idempotent

Tags: http, specifications, http-patch

Its mentioned on [HTTP Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) that `PATCH` is `not` idempotent.

The basic definition of idempotent is:

> An idempotent HTTP method is a HTTP method that can be called many
>   times without different outcomes

So If we make an HTTP call

```
PATCH /users/1
{
    "username": "dummyUser"
}
```

No matter how many times we call above HTTP endpoint, it always implies to update the `username` of user `1` to `dummyUser`.

And that's pretty much same for any `PATCH` request to update 1 or many attributes of any resource.

Then why does HTTP Spec specify that `PATCH` is `not` idempotent?

Comment: (a) Your example for PUT does not update just the username, it *replaces* the whole resource with the payload. (b) For PATCH it depends on what the patch semantics for the payload's media type are.

Comment: Just updated the question description. It was supposed to be patch in the snippet.

Comment: There's still no media type (Content-Type) in the example, so it's impossible to say what PATCH is supposed to do here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, it's important to clarify that `Idempotent: No` doesn't mean it's never, ever idempotent, it means it's not *necessarily* idempotent, i.e. it isn't required to be.

So, in your example, it does seem to be idempotent, as the state of the resource is identical after multiple repeated calls of the same `PATCH` request.

But consider a hypothetical `PATCH` request like:

```
PATCH /users/1

successful_logins++
```

This request increments the `successful_logins` attribute of the user by one each time it's called.  As you can see, it's not idempotent, since successive requests cause additional modification to the resource.

This is in contrast to the `PUT` method, which would have to contain the absolute values of all the resource's attributes.